# PHP how do I split this option string to this kind of array

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, string, split

This string comes from ajax GET, I have decided to make a option "field".

String: width(400),height(200),age(99),string(test)

How do I split this into this kind of array:

```
$myArray =
[
   'width' => 400,
   'height' => 200,
   'age' => 99,
   'string => 'test'
];
```

Please take a note that integers has to integers, to make it easier for calculations.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I was simply looking for the "Answered" button, thanks everyone, the ajax was the most interesting, but maybe pain in the ass to maintain.

Comment: I still think complicated string parsing isn't the best solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "width(400),height(200),age(99),string(test)";
preg_match_all('/(\d|\w)+/', $str,$matches);
$array = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i += 2) { 
    $array[$matches[0][$i]] = $matches[0][$i+1];
}
print_r($array);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [width] => 400
    [height] => 200
    [age] => 99
    [string] => test
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not change the way you send the data?

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: {width:400, height: 200, age: 99, aString: "test"},
  success: success
});
```

That will be easier to process in PHP. Save yourself a headache :)

Answer (score 2):

The regex can probably be improved (it's not my strong point), but you could do something like this:

```
$string = 'width(400),height(200),age(99),string(test)';
preg_match_all('/(\w+)\((\w+)\)/', $string, $matches);

$output = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Which outputs:

```
array
  'width' => string '400' (length=3)
  'height' => string '200' (length=3)
  'age' => string '99' (length=2)
  'string' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

Comment: Ended up using this since this was the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a PHP `print_r` to send this variable in GET then dont do it.

You could perhaps encode the data(array) into JSON(by using `json_encode`) and then `url_encode` it and then send it in the GET variable value.

And while receiving it, do the reverse, `url_decode` first and then `json_decode` to get it in the array format you are looking for

Or else send each `width, height, age and string` as separate variable to save all the effort